# Raise of TRIAC A1-Gate potential under load after triggering

Tags: triac

During experiments with a TRIAC I noticed that appart from the triggering signal the A1-Gate voltage remains 0V under no load condition. 
Under load conditions the A1-Gate voltage remains elevated after triggering up to the moment the TRIAC stops conducting.

In the information found so far I find only information on the latching  current nothing on the above mentioned effect.

Why is this happend or do I make an error in the measuring procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the gate of a thyristor acts as a voltage source when the thyristor is conducting. The voltage is generally a bit higher than the gate trigger voltage and will be of the same polarity as MT2 for a triac.

That means that the gate voltage can swing from (say) +1.3V for triggering to (say) -1.4V when it turns on in quadrant IV (and the reverse in quadrant II. Or it can barely change in quadrants I and III.

---

In some cases, impedances connected to the gate of a thyristor can have noticeable effects on the commutation or holding characteristics. Thyristors designed to be reliably commutated directly from the gate were called GTO (Gate Turn Off) devices.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know but my book gives this equivalent circuit if A2 > A1 and for A1 > A2.

[image]

So, this equivalent circuit confirms your measurement.